# Tool to calculate how many "real" frames per second there is in a video

Tags: windows, web-apps, video, video-editing

Is there any tool (free if possible, but commercial software is also OK), that allow to calculate how many frames per second there is in a video ?

By calculating "how many real frames per second" I did not mean a tool that return the FPS information stored in the video header (that windows explorer or any video editing tool like `VirtualDub` can give).

I mean a tool that would take each frame, check if it is different from previous frame (with some threshold) and based on that will report FPS information.

For example a video source could have been recorded at 60 fps but if you check frames themselves its only 30 fps (each frame is "doubled").

Such tools exists, please check these videos (it seems same tool is used in both) :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fbYyMq4cGU
- http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-trials-evolution-tech-interview (see video in middle of the page)

In these videos, I'm not sure either this is a software or hardware solution. I'm looking for a software one.

Comment: Do you care about operating system? how about web-apps? Do you care about pricing?

Comment: @NickWilde : I have added tags to give more information, as suggested. I have no specific budget but it should be reasonable for non professional use (a 1500USD solution with specific hardware is not OK)

Comment: I am not familiar with video data formats, but don"t you also need the time (e.g. seconds) to calculate the FPS rate? Or is the *real* time stored in file video headers?